# how to interpret a prepositional phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Thank you for your time. Please take look at the following:

"The passage is primarily with summarizing the reasons for the rejection of an establish theory by the scientific community."

Regarding "by the scientific community", I conjectured up two interpretation but prefer the first one:

1. It modifies "the rejection". So the sentence means: the article is mainly about the community's reasons to reject a theory.
2. It modifies "an established theory". And, the sentence means the articles summarized the reasons to reject one of the community's established theory.

I can't figure out which is the more appropriate. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: It modifies the whole NP "the rejection of an establish theory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The passage is primarily with[sic] summarizing the reasons for the rejection of an [established] theory by the scientific community."

The prepositional phrase 'by the scientific community' modifies the noun phrase 'the rejection of an established theory'.